# How can I terminate system()?

Tags: c, unix, sh

From C program, I call a script file (.sh) by running `system()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

system("/home/root/Server_video.sh");

}
```

I want to stop/start running script file again and again (e.g. run for 60 s, terminate, run for 60 s, ...). This is because script file runs a video server which adds delay as time passes.

What is the way implementing this? I'm a newbie and any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`fork(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork)/[`exec(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec)/[`wait(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait)/[`kill(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/kill) rather than [`system(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system), and you'll be able to implement what you're trying.

Answer (score 1):

As Carl Norum said, you can't use system, but instead need to use fork, exec, and kill. Here's an example.

**C Program**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  pid_t pid;
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {  // repeat 3 times
    char str[10];
    sprintf(str, "%d", i);

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
      perror("fork");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (pid == 0) {
      execlp("./script.sh", "script.sh", str, NULL);
      perror("exec");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }else{
      sleep(5);  // let script run for 5 seconds
      kill(pid, SIGKILL);
      printf("--- parent\n");
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**Shell Script**

```
#!/bin/sh

while :; do
  echo "script $1"
  sleep 1
done
```

**Output**

```
$ ./a.out
script 0
script 0
script 0
script 0
script 0
--- parent
script 1
script 1
script 1
script 1
script 1
--- parent
script 2
script 2
script 2
script 2
script 2
--- parent
```

Comment: Your example really helped. However, `kill(pid, SIGKILL);` didn't terminated video server from running, so I used `system("sudo fuser -k 8080/tcp");` as video server uses port 8080.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this for the learning experience, that's great, but there's no other reason to do this in C.  It would be much easier to do it directly in the shell.  If you want to use C *and* do it in the shell, try:

```
#include<stdlib.h>

int
main(void)
{
        system( "while :; do /home/root/Server_video.sh & sleep 60; kill $!; done" );
        return 0;
}
```

(Please note that this is somewhat tongue-in-cheek.  Just use the shell script directly.)